# Using SQL SEQUENCEs with Django

Tags: django, django-orm

I need to generate numbers that are unique and in sequence (for easy traceability). Also, they should be as gapless as possible (for decent non-repudiation).

SQL SEQUENCEs are the obvious answer. What's the cleanest way to use them with Django 1.8 and MySQL? They doesn't seem to be a good way to use SEQUENCEs with Django.

Comment: MySQL doesn't support arbitrary sequences, other than the autoincrement field Django already uses for the pk.

Comment: @Daniel Roseman Oh that's lame. I thought that was a basic feature for any SQL DBMS. What would be "the way" to solve this, then? Exploitin the autoincrement feature?

Answer (score 0):

Since MySQL doesn't have separate sequences the only clear way is to create a new table that has autoincrementing IDs.

Thinking about the design in a super relational way, I am also able to store other related data in the new table.

The other data is otherwise being redundantly stored in other tables (redundantly since some of the other tables are for logging). However, storing the data in a more organised way will result in better traceability and smaller database size.